# Xcode 7.3 unable to find utility "make"

Tags: xcode, macos, npm

I am facing this issue on macos Sierra.

When i try to install the npm module i get this error.

make: error: unable to find utility "make", not a developer tool or in PATH

Answer (score 0):

You should install the xcode commandline tools. That will make sure make is in the path